# iOS : How to add drop shadow and stroke shadow on UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, dropshadow, strokeshadow

I want to add **drop shadow** and **stroke shadow** on `UIView`
This is what my designer given me to apply shadow,

- For drop shadow, he told me to use RGB(176,199,226) with 90% opacity, distance-3 and size-5
- For stroke shadow, he told to apply, RGB(209,217,226) of size-1 and 100% opacity.

This is photoshop applied effects screen,

[image][image]

**The view with the required shadow (expected output)**

[image]

**I tried the following to get the drop shadow**

```
viewCheck.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
viewCheck.layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
viewCheck.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(.0f,2.5f);
viewCheck.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5f;
viewCheck.layer.shadowOpacity = .9f;
viewCheck.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:176.f/255.f green:199.f/255.f blue:226.f/255.f alpha:1.f].CGColor;
viewCheck.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:viewCheck.bounds].CGPath;
```

And this is the result of it,

[image]

I'm having problem in understanding how I can apply stroke and drop shadow as showing into photoshop screenshots (I've added above). How to apply Distance, Spread, Size, Position?

Can someone point me to a guide to applying these kind of shadows? There's lots of shadow effects coming out and I want to learn how it can be possible instead asking each of the questions here!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe most of configuration you look for can be achieved by employing the `shadowPath` property.

```
viewCheck.layer.shadowRadius  = 1.5f;
viewCheck.layer.shadowColor   = [UIColor colorWithRed:176.f/255.f green:199.f/255.f blue:226.f/255.f alpha:1.f].CGColor;
viewCheck.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
viewCheck.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9f;
viewCheck.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

UIEdgeInsets shadowInsets     = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -1.5f, 0);
UIBezierPath *shadowPath      = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(viewCheck.bounds, shadowInsets)];
viewCheck.layer.shadowPath    = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

e.g, by setting `shadowInsets` this way

```
UIEdgeInsets shadowInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -1.5f, 0);
```

you will get a nice desirable shadow:

[image]

You can decide now how you want the shadow rectangle to be constructed by controlling the shadow path rectangle insets.

Answer (score 12):

Following are the steps for  `User Defined Runtime Attribute`.

1. Open a storyboard or xib file in Interface Builder.
2. In Interface Builder, select the object to add the attribute to.
3. Choose View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector.

The Identity inspector appears in the utility area. As shown below, the user defined runtime attributes editor is one of the items in the inspector.

[image]

4. Click the Add button (+) in the lower left of the user defined runtime attributes editor.

[image]

Comment: amazing solution. Thanks bro

Answer (score 6):

For give **Border** Of `UIView`.

Add `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"` fram work.

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0; // set as you want.
myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor; // set color as you want.
myView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0; // set as you want.
```

Comment: myView.layer.shadowColor = ...;

Comment: myView.layer.shadowOffset = ...;

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry, I only have the Swift solution but heres my UIView extensions which I use to do this task:

```
// MARK: Layer Extensions
extension UIView {

    func setCornerRadius(#radius: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    func addShadow(#offset: CGSize, radius: CGFloat, color: UIColor, opacity: Float, cornerRadius: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.layer.shadowOffset = offset
        self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.CGColor
        if let r = cornerRadius {
            self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: r).CGPath
        }
    }

    func addBorder(#width: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        self.layer.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    func drawStroke(#width: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.w, height: self.w), cornerRadius: self.w/2)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer ()
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

}
```

I never tried it but you could just paste this code to any Swift file and probably call them from Obj-C code.